# Тип данных для столбца Продолжительность в MySQL (PhpMyAdmin)

Tags: mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin, типы-данных

Какой тип данных можно использовать для поля Продолжительность в phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Выбор проще сделать, когда знаете, что есть в вашем распоряжении. Прочитайте [документацию](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html), прикиньте что за данные могут у вас быть и подберите что-нибудь подходящее.

Comment: Если значение Продолжительность - это время, не превышающее 1 месяц, то тип данных TIME - самое оно...

Answer (score 1):

Если для Вас продолжительность это часы, минуты или секунды, то используйте обычный формат INTEGER.

Если под продолжительностью Вы понимаете какой-то конечное время / дату - то DATETIME.

Comment: int можно выбрать разный в зависимости от того, продолжительность чего используется. Если это продолжительность какого-то процесса, то возможность указать -1 как бесконечную продолжительность может быть полезна. Если это продолжительность видеоролика в секундах, то можно использовать беззнаковый int, и, возможно, будет достаточно mediumint. Если это дни подписки, то можно ограничиться и smallint. Впрочем, на небольших объёмах данных это ни на что особенно не повлияет.